# Migration from npm to Yarn 2 PnP: ts-loader doesn't find webpack

Tags: node.js, nestjs, yarnpkg, yarnpkg-v2, yarn-v2

I am working on a [NestJS](https://nestjs.com/) project.

Until now I have used `npm`. Now I want to migrate to [Yarn 2](https://yarnpkg.com/) with [Zero-Install](https://yarnpkg.com/features/zero-installs) an [P'n'P](https://yarnpkg.com/features/pnp).

However, after following the migration instruction, I get this error:

```
~/IdeaProjects/service on feature/yarn-migration ⇡3 ❯ yarn explain peer-requirements p0b548                                                                                                                                                                                                           at 17:36:06
➤ YN0000: service@workspace:. doesn't provide webpack, breaking the following requirements:

➤ YN0000: ts-loader@npm:8.0.14 [0b662] → * ✘
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained by the message, `ts-loader` has a peer dependency on `webpack`. Hence you must add `webpack` to your dependencies.